# How to select only nodes that are not only spaces using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML document:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="572705D7" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidP="00CA0169" w:rsidR="00CA0169" w:rsidRDefault="00CA0169" w:rsidRPr="00777A35">
    <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>synthesized in cyanobacteria under unsuitable condition</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I currently select all nodes that begin with  as follows:

```
text_nodes = p.xpath('w:r')
```

However, I would like to select only those text nodes that contain text and are not only spaces as the first  node is as shown in the xml sample above.

I have extended the String Class to test for spaces as follows:

```
class String
  def spaces?
    x = self =~ /^\s+$/
    x == 0
  end
end
```

So I can do:

```
element.text.spaces?
```

I just don't know how to put it together with the `p.xpath('w:r')`to select only nodes that are NOT only spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w:r[normalize-space(.) != '']
```

as your XPath expression should do.

Comment: Thanks you zc485. Would this work for any number of spaces or just one space?

Comment: `normalize-space` removes all leading and trailing spaces which equals to an empty string if no other characters are present.